# How to return non-static variable from static method?

Tags: java, static

Even through these reference `Tri1`, I am not able to return base value.

```
public class Triangle {

    private double base;

    Triangle Tri1 = new Triangle();

    public static double getBase() 
    { 
        return Tri1.base; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Tri1` a static variable:

```
public class Triangle {

private double base;

static Triangle Tri1 = new Triangle();

public static double getBase() 
  { 
    return Tri1.base; 
  }
}
```

Or make `getBase` instance method:

```
public class Triangle {

private double base;

Triangle Tri1 = new Triangle();

public double getBase() 
  { 
    return Tri1.base; 
  }
}
```

You can not return instance variable from static method.

Answer (score 0):

You try to call the private member of a specific object. To access base, you would have to make it static. But then every triangle has the same base value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triangle {

  private double base;

  static Triangle Tri1 = new Triangle();

  public static double getBase() 
  { 
    return Tri1.base; 
  }
}
```

Please make above changes. It runs without error. Please remember, from static methods, we have access only static members of that class, be it a static variable or another static method. 
Static methods are loaded into memory before the non-static members get loaded..so any access of non-static members from static methods looks like you are going to access something that is not created .so you get a compilation error.